# C -Parameter name omitted? Can't find error

Tags: c, hardware, intel

So I'm programming the Intel 8253 PIT for college but I don't think the context is relevant for this question. So, I'm trying to compile my file and I keep getting the "Parameter Name Omitted" error and I really don't know why.

This is all compiled in a Minix VM connected to the college server. I just cd to the folder and type "Make" and the commands are automatic. Really don't know details. More info below:

Function:

```
int timer_test_read_config(uint8_t timer, enum timer_status_field field) {
  uint8_t temp;
  timer_display_conf(timer,temp,field);
  return 1;
}
```

Enum declaration:

```
enum timer_status_field {
    all,        /*!< configuration/status */
    initial,    /*!< timer initialization mode */
    mode,       /*!< timer counting mode */
    base        /*!< timer counting base */
};
```

Error message:

```
lab.c:33:5: error: parameter name omitted
int timer_test_read_config(uint8_t timer, enum timer_status_field field) {
```

Why am I getting the error? I really don't get it. I'm probably being really dumb but yeah ahah I need some help. Thanks!

Comment: Please always add the exact error message, don't paraphrase

Comment: I'd add some detail on the compile command you use and the error you see.

Comment: Also add the the declaration of the enum.

Comment: Really Minix??  What compiler / version are you using?

Comment: @PeterCordes yep. Minix 3. It's a pain in the in ass but oh well. We log into the college servers and then compile and test our programs in there. We use it to backup our files in a SVN group repository (Redmine) as well

Comment: The code as you posted it compiles without that error for me. Either what you put here isn't what you're actually trying to compile, or you have some #define in one of your headers that's breaking something.

Answer (score 1):

Old answer below, invalidated by an edit to the question.

Now it's unanswerable without a more detailed MCVE, because the current code compiles just fine with gcc, if you add `#include <stdint.h>`.  (https://godbolt.org/z/VKZmU4).

---

You forgot the trailing `;` at the end of your `enum` declaration.

```
enum timer_status_field {
    all,        /*!< configuration/status */
    initial,    /*!< timer initialization mode */
    mode,       /*!< timer counting mode */
    base        /*!< timer counting base */
};  /// Note added ; on this line
```

This compiles fine.  Compile your original enum declaration in a file by itself to get a clearer error message:

```
foo.c:6:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ at end of input
 }
 ^
```

With stuff after the `}`, your compiler was trying to interpret it as a variable of that type, because `enum { foo, bar } varname;` is a valid declaration.

---

With this change, your entire code compiles just fine (with a `#include <stdint.h>`), just warning about undeclared functions of course.

Comment: @pcordes sorry, my bad! In the code itself the ";" is present, just forgot it in the post. Again, sorry for lost time and a thank you for your help!

Comment: @AfonsoMendonça: then post a [mcve] in your question, because what you posted (including the `;`) compiles just fine if you add a `#include <stdint.h>`.  https://godbolt.org/z/VKZmU4 on Godbolt only shows warnings for the implicit declaration of `timer_display_conf`, and for using `temp` uninitialized.

Comment: @pcordes alright, that was helpful! Will probably make a new question following those guidelines. Thanks a lot! I'm new here so I'm still learning about how to make questions the right way so that people can truly help me. Again, thanks. Cheers!

Comment: @AfonsoMendonça: you can edit this one to improve it and turn it into a MCVE of whatever you were doing.

Comment: @AfonsoMendonça: or you can simply delete your question if you don't want to edit this one for some reason.  (I might need to delete this answer first, let me know if SO doesn't let click "delete".)